# Using jQuery .delay() on 'this'

Tags: jquery

I'm using aniCollection to make three boxes fade in + slide up when the page loads. Its been working great so far but i thought i'd try making the boxes appear one at a time for a better visual effect. This is the aniCollection code for the slideup + fadein:

```
var element = $('#square');

element.mouseover(function(){
element.toggleClass('fadeInUp animated');
element.one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(e){
     $(e.target).removeClass('fadeInUp animated');
  });
});
```

This is my attempt to delay each box individually with `.delay(counter)`:

```
var counter = 0;
var welcomeBoxes = $('#welcomeBoxes');
welcomeBoxes.each(function(){
    counter += 300;
    $(this).delay(counter).toggleClass('fadeInUp animated');
    $(this).delay(counter).one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(e){
        $(e.target).removeClass('fadeInUp animated');
    });
})
```

Nothing changes when I run it. The boxes still all fade in at the same time. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: id must be unique .. use class instead .. so loop through the same id its totally wrong

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: I'm blind... thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st:** as I said in comment .. Id must be unique .. so don't use same id for more than one element .. `use class=""`  instead of `id=""`

**2nd:** after you change to class you can loop through class like this

```
var welcomeBoxes = $('.welcomeBoxes'); // use (.) for class  like (#) for id
welcomeBoxes.each(function(i){ // i mean index of element and its start from 0
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('fadeInUp animated');
    $(this).one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(e){
        $(e.target).removeClass('fadeInUp animated');
    });
  }, i * 2000); // 2000 is a setTimeout duration you can change it as you like and we use i * 2000 to make a delay we need 
})
```

Comment: Extremely helpful. Thank you